# Paragraph text not appearing in Featherlight lightbox

Tags: featherlight.js, featherlight

I followed the setup / instructions for adding a Featherlight lightbox to a button on my Squarespace site and everything worked out well with one issue. The paragraph text is not appearing in the popup. I get a white lightbox with a black close button, all functioning properly. But the text does not show. When I inspect the box, I am able to highlight the text and see that it exists + the color is dark blue (not white, so should be showing against the white lightbox background). Any idea what may be happening?

Here's my code:

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#learn-more" class="sqs-block-button-element--large sqs-block-button-element">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
<div id="learn-more" style="text-align:center;">
<p>PARAGRAPH TEXT HERE</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: change style="display:none;" into style="display:block;" / or remove  style="display:none;" from div element

Comment: @Raphael — Thanks for your edit and reply. The solution you've proposed will make the div content ever-present. The goal is for it to only appear when a link is clicked . My issue is that text-based content does not appear within the pop-up. Images, for instance, do appear.

Comment: visibility of the text should be dependant on the visibility of the popup - not the text itself. Once the popup is shown - show content, otherwise hide popup.

Comment: can I have your popup html code ?